# Dual-Boot system with Ubuntu cannot access Windows 10 (grub update and boot-repair not working)

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I've recently entered in possess of a desktop computer with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. Booting it, it will immediately start Ubuntu and I'm currently not able to log in into windows. I've already tried to update grub (`sudo update-grub`) and used `boot-repair` but still I can't access any boot menu when restarting the computer. Curious thing is that when I turn the cimputer on, pressing any key to try to enter the BIOS menu will freeze the computer and I will hve to reset it.
How can I get to any boot menu to try to boot windows?

If it can be of any help, I have the boot-repair Summary availabe that I attach below.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Boot repair below:

```
boot-repair-4ppa129                                              [20210416_1705]
```

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

config script
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
search.fs_uuid aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75 root hd0,msdos6 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
·ò
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr
```

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS CurrentSession on sda6
OS#2:   Windows 10 (loader) on sda1

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-133-generic root=UUID=aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

===================================== UEFI =====================================

This installed-session is not in EFI-mode.

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0f348572
Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048 247578623 247576576 118.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       247580670 488396799 240816130 114.9G  5 Extended
sda5       425900032 488396799  62496768  29.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
sda6       247580672 425900031 178319360    85G 83 Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0f34850a
Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1  *          2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb2          1026048 1973436415 1972410368 940.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb3       1973436416 3907028212 1933591797   922G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:250GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Samsung SSD 750:;
1:1049kB:127GB:127GB:ntfs::boot;
3:127GB:250GB:123GB:::;
6:127GB:218GB:91.3GB:ext4::;
5:218GB:250GB:32.0GB:linux-swap(v1)::;
sdb:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST2000DM001-1ER1:;
1:1049kB:525MB:524MB:ntfs::boot;
2:525MB:1010GB:1010GB:ntfs::;
3:1010GB:2000GB:990GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL           PARTLABEL
sdb
ââsdb2 ntfs     290CF0EB732D1122                     0f34850a-02
ââsdb3 ext4     ff64d0e2-e704-4f97-9ab0-268d41aba02c 0f34850a-03
ââsdb1 ntfs     D60AC35D0AC3396F                     0f34850a-01                          System Reserved
sda
ââsda5 swap     6f56bff8-3f7a-43f7-901b-8d69d871f171 0f348572-05
ââsda3                                               0f348572-03
ââsda1 ntfs     FA70856470852909                     0f348572-01
ââsda6 ext4     aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75 0f348572-06

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

```
    Avail Use% Mounted on
```

sda1    14.8G  87% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda6    51.9G  33% /
sdb1   469.5M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
sdb2    34.1G  96% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
sdb3     694G  18% /home

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda6   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
sdb1   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb2   rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb3   rw,relatime,data=ordered

====================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Windows 10 (loader) (on sda1)   FA70856470852909
Ubuntu   aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-133-generic   aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-133-generic (upstart)   gnulinux-4.15.0-133-generic-init-upstart-aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-132-generic   aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-132-generic (upstart)   gnulinux-4.15.0-132-generic-init-upstart-aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75
Windows 10 (loader) (on sda1)   FA70856470852909

#### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober

#### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware

========================== sda6/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

## / was on /dev/sda6 during installation

UUID=aa4b1772-9cb9-4357-9c23-6e1667335b75 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

## /home was on /dev/sdb3 during installation

UUID=ff64d0e2-e704-4f97-9ab0-268d41aba02c /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

## swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation

UUID=6f56bff8-3f7a-43f7-901b-8d69d871f171 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT="menuentry 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-FA70856470852909' {"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
```

123.893581390 = 133.029720064  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
124.053798676 = 133.201752064  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
146.322090149 = 157.112147968  boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-132-generic                1
193.817787170 = 208.110264320  boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-133-generic                1
193.817787170 = 208.110264320  vmlinuz                                        1
146.322090149 = 157.112147968  vmlinuz.old                                    1
146.608264923 = 157.419425792  boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-132-generic             4
194.100215912 = 208.413519872  boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-133-generic             3
194.100215912 = 208.413519872  initrd.img                                     3
146.608264923 = 157.419425792  initrd.img.old                                 4

===================== sda6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12512 mar 21  2018 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11082 mar 21  2018 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 mar 21  2018 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 mar 21  2018 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 mar 21  2018 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 mar 21  2018 41_custom

========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive ==========

sdc

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda6 into the MBRs of all disks (except live-disks and removable disks without OS).
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (ATA Samsung SSD 750) disk!

Comment: Is your grub configuration set to hide the actual boot loading process and boot directly into the OS? I don't know much about MBR but I do know that grub can be "hidden" and boot without asking, like another well known bootloader.

**EDIT** this looks like a problem `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` for this scenario

Comment: Actually I tried to comment the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` inside file `/etc/default/grub` but still, after rebooting I get directly the ubuntu log in screen.